# How can I know spark-core version?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform

I am using spark 1.5.2 in hdp, and version for hadoop is 2.7.1.2.3.4.7-4. When I attempt to add jars in maven pom file like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I dont know where to find version for spark-core. There are 2.11 and 2.10.
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That version you are mentioning denotes which version of Scala you want to use for the spark-core.

You need to check Scala's version on your cluster to know if it's 2.10 that you need or 2.11.